# How to remove form control in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, controls

```
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();

if (Cat0.Text == "test")
{
    txt1.Name = "testText";
    txt1.Width = 170;
    txt1.Height = 21;
    txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 145);

    txt2.Name = "testText2";
    txt2.Width = 170;
    txt2.Height = 21;
    txt2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 171);

    panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
    panel1.Controls.Add(txt2);
}
else
{
    if (panel1.Controls.Contains(txt1)) // not working
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(txt1);
    }
}
```

The `if else` statement is not working. So I can't remove the form control in this block. I think the reason for not working is because of the `txt1` control created with code.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? From the code shown, it will never enter the `if` because in the surrounding `else`the control is never added to `panel1`.

Comment: just create a member for the textbox and check for the member. You create a complete new instance of a textbox which is not the same textbox added before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
if (Cat0.Text == "test")
{
     txt1.Name = "testText";
     txt1.Width = 170;
     txt1.Height = 21;
     txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 145);
     txt2.Name = "testText2";
     txt2.Width = 170;
     txt2.Height = 21;
     txt2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 171);
     panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
     panel1.Controls.Add(txt2);
}
else
{
     foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
     {
         if (item.Name == "testText")
         {
              panel1.Controls.Remove(item);
              break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: But the name is `txt1.Name = "testText";`

Comment: This solves a non-existent problem: There's nothing to remove because `txt1` is never added to `panel1` in the program flow shown.

Comment: @Filburt : Can you read code? Both textboxes are added to the panel.

Comment: @Filburt nope guess this function is called on button click event then it seems all good

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Can *you* read? They are added in the outer `if`. There is nothing added in the `else` branch.

Comment: @Filburt : when calling the method the first time and the Cat0 textbox contains the text "test" the controls are added. the second time the method is called the cat0 textbox text is different and the textboxes added in the first call should be removed. this is what I understand from OP.

Comment: @Filburt guess there is one form with 1 textbox named 'Cat0' and one button  and on clicking on that button you performing this operation, now tell me is it working workflow or not ?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz the instance you are creating is never added to panel1 because you always create a new instance, you don't have a reference to the orignal instance of the textbox. Thank god there is a GarbageCollector in c# :-)

Comment: @Pazi01 the references are not removed via GC as the panel1 contains the instance and therefore the reference is still there. Only if the control/reference is removed or the panel will be disposed the instances will be removed via GC.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz i mean the instance you are creating and never adding to the panel...

Comment: @Pazi01 Now I know what you mean. Both textbox instances should be created in the If block as they will be never used in the else block. :-)

Comment: @SebastianSchulz that's what i meant. I've provided a full answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are creating a new TextBox each time you enter the method. Move your `TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();` and `TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();` outside the method and I think it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You always create a new instance so you don't have the right instance in your local variable.

Here is a way to do:

```
  TextBox txt1 = null;

  //Lookup txt1
  foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
  {
    if (item.Name == "testText")
    {
      txt1 = (TextBox)item;
    }
  }      

  TextBox txt2 = null;
  //Lookup txt2
  foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
  {
    if (item.Name == "testText2")
    {
      txt2 = (TextBox)item;
    }
  }
  if (Cat0.Text == "test")
  {
    if (txt1 == null)
    {
      //only if txt1 not found add it
      txt1 = new TextBox();
      txt1.Name = "testText";
      txt1.Width = 170;
      txt1.Height = 21;
      txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 145);
      panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
    }

    if (txt2 == null)
    {
      txt2 = new TextBox();
      txt2.Name = "testText2";
      txt2.Width = 170;
      txt2.Height = 21;
      txt2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 171);
      panel1.Controls.Add(txt2);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (panel1.Controls.Contains(txt1))
    {
      panel1.Controls.Remove(txt1);
    }
  }
}
```